# What was the original title of Jewish kings?

Tags: ancient-history, israel

Thinking about King Solomon, and other Jewish leaders who bear the title "king" in English sources (for example King David).

Seems a bit strange, because the word *king* is of Germanic origin. Which means that Jews must have been calling their rulers differently.

So what was the word and why people can't use it directly (For example we don't call Arab Sheikhs Kings).

Comment: It's probably a translation choice...a Christian reader of an English language Bible is meant to associate these biblical leaders with their own kings and therefore it uses the same word for them.

Comment: [Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s)](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/785/26786)

Comment: Odd question. The word king may be of German origin, but it is now an English word. We use it for French, Welsh, Scottish, Italian, Hungarian, etc.  We probably use it for the majority of monarchs.   (other than those with religious roles).  Why does the question call special attention to Jews?  The interesting question is why we use non-English words to refer to rulers (like Sheikh or Tsar)?

Comment: @MCW Accident. Habit. The random choice of someone unknown years ago that happened to catch on.

Comment: Darius the Persian was called a king. The first rulers of Rome were called kings. Agamemnon is [king](https://www.worldhistory.org/Agamemnon_(Person)/). This question doesn't even begin to show a basic amount of research, and the direct reference to "Jews" reeks of some sort of anti-Semitic bent (intentional or otherwise).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The relevant Hebrew word for king is **Melekh**, cognate with various Semitic terms such as Malik (more information can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malik)). Why this word came to be translated into English as king instead of being transliterated is an interesting question. If we take the name of the biblical book of Kings, the Septuagint translated the word in a less literal way as the book of Kingships, Βασιλειῶν. The entry in [Strong's concordance can be found here](https://biblehub.com/greek/932.htm). This may hint at an answer to why translation was preferred, as Biblical kings were often invoked as [Mirrors for princes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mirrors_for_princes). This genre was popular from an early date, see for example, Alexander's interest in Achilles from the Iliad (This is discussed at length in Robin Lane Fox's biography of Alexander the Great). Perhaps the feeling was that translating the term highlighted the relevance of the material to a broader audience? Whatever the reason, translating the term became common, as after the Septuagint the Aramaic translations also translated the term, even though the Hebrew word would have been completely comprehensible to an Aramaic speaker, as did the Vulgate. By the time it came to Wycliffe and later English translations, a precedent had already been established.

Comment: Looking it over, it seems to me like if there's any shade of difference between the terms, its that Germanic "Kings" originally ruled over a nation (a specific tribe or people), while NW Semitic "mlk" tended to rule city states. However, each has been used for the other.